# Report metadata cannot be found after pulling renamed report folder with DX

Tags: reporting, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have a report and folder in my scratch org. The report was renamed from `Custom_Reports` to `Org_Reports`. Now I receive the following error when attempting to execute the `force:source:pull -f` command:

Entity of type 'Report' named `Custom_Reports/Org_Best_Accounts_Last_Month` cannot be found. It appears to be trying to pull the report under the old folder name.

How can I reset dx so that it is no longer trying to pull this report with the old folder name?

Update: Modifying the .forceignore file to exclude the directory did not resolve the error.